# How well supported is the "input" event for live()

Tags: jquery

We are using jQuery 1.4.4 on a website and I had a problem which resulted from using the **keyup** event on a textbox.  The problem was that the user was somehow managing to change the values without actually typing.  I quickly noticed three causes:

- Autocompletion in the textbox
- You can drag a value into the text box
- You can right click -> paste values

I had a look around and I noticed that I could use the **change** event to resolve the problem.  This works fine for autocomplete but it doesn't resolve the problem for dragging values into the textbox. I couldn't get anything to work and then I came across the **input** event.

This event seems to resolve all my problems, it's the only event which I need to use to account for keyup, dragging values in and using autocomplete.

My question is simple:  How well is this supported? I can't seem to find any information on it.

Edit: just to clarify, I am aware that live is deprecated, we have to keep the jquery version the same so that won't be affecting us.  Thanks for the consideration though!

Comment: Dragging text into a textbox will trigger the on change event. You just have to lose the focus from the textbox before the change event will fire. http://jsfiddle.net/MMmzx/

Comment: Thanks for the comment Elliot.  I am aware that people get confused with having to lose focus for change to work (with autocomplete) but this is not the case with dragging text into the box.  At least in the version of Chrome I am using, the event is not fired.  I just re-verified it to make sure.

Comment: I tried it out on my Chrome browser--it seemed to fire the on change event for me. Did you try my Fiddle?

Comment: the website seems down at the moment, I can't open it.

Comment: @ElliotB. Are you sure you are dragging text in? I just verified it on your jsfiddle and the alert message does not pop up.

Comment: Yep that's what I'm doing--are you remembering to click outside of the textbox after you've dragged the content in?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input basic support exists for all browsers..

(*but in regards to the question title, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) syntax*)

Comment: Thanks for the comment about live being deprecated.  I am actually aware of that already but we don't need to change anything as we won't touch the version of jquery we're working with, it's too risky as the application is extremely complex.  Thanks for the extra comment though!

Comment: @James, fair enough. Had to state it for other readers as well :)

Comment: Not that it matters too much anymore, but `input` isn't supported by older IE browsers.